# Is it possible to split a lengthy form into multiple pages in ms access?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to split a lengthy form into multiple pages. I would like to use 'next' and 'previous' buttons to navigate within the same form through multiple pages, how do I go about it

I've tried page break and tab control but it doesn't seem to give me what I'm looking for, what can i do instead

I tried creating multiple forms and creating previous and forward buttons on these forms to move forward and backwards through these forms like pages. However I would like to create a save button on the final page to save everything inputted into these forms so far. how do I go about this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Use a [Tab Control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-tabbed-form-6869dee9-3ab7-4f3d-8e65-3a84183c9815)

Comment: Can you explain what part of 'what you are looking for' the tab control doesn't seem to give you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, insert a page-break in a lengthy form:

[image]

Then you can scroll between "pages" and use code like this:

```vb
Private Sub BtnNext_Click()

  Me!txtPage.Value = Me!txtPage.Value + 1

  Call SetNavigationButtons

End Sub


Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()

  Me!txtPage.Value = Me!txtPage.Value - 1

  Call SetNavigationButtons

End Sub


Private Sub SetNavigationButtons()
  
  ' Const cintPageFirst = 1
  ' Const cintPageLast = 7

  Dim intPage           As Integer
  Dim intEnablePrevious As Integer
  Dim intEnableNext     As Integer
  Dim intEnableFinish   As Integer
  Dim intEnableCancel   As Integer

  intPage = Me!txtPage.Value
  intEnablePrevious = True
  intEnableNext = True
  intEnableFinish = True
  intEnableCancel = True

  Select Case intPage
    Case 0
      ' Reset.
      intEnablePrevious = False
      intEnableNext = False
      intEnableFinish = False
    Case 1
      Me!btnCancel.SetFocus
      intEnablePrevious = False
      If Me!txtFakturaAntal1.Value = 0 Then
        intEnableFinish = False
      End If
    Case 2
      If Me!txtFakturaAntal2.Value = 0 Then
        Me!btnCancel.SetFocus
        intEnableNext = False
        intEnableFinish = False
      End If
    Case 3
    Case 4
    Case 5
    Case 6
    Case 7
      If Me!btnPrevious.Enabled = True Then
        Me!btnPrevious.SetFocus
      Else
        Me!btnCancel.SetFocus
      End If
      intEnableNext = False
  End Select

  Me!btnCancel.Enabled = intEnableCancel
  If intPage = 0 Then
    Me!btnCancel.SetFocus
    intPage = 1
    Me!txtPage.Value = intPage
  End If
  Me!btnPrevious.Enabled = intEnablePrevious
  Me!btnNext.Enabled = intEnableNext
  Me!btnFinish.Enabled = intEnableFinish

  DoCmd.GoToPage intPage

End Sub
```

Comment: my form passes the Standard length of an access form so it ends up only showing me one page

Comment: Well, if one page only, no other pages are to be shown. Extend the height if you wish to display other pages - as the behaviour of a typical wizard.

Comment: How interesting -- I not used a page break in years - that goes back all the way to the 1992 version of Access, and is in fact a "long forgotten" approach here. The other suggestions to introduce a tab control is probably the best, but this answer is certainly one for the history books!